# Padding child elements of a responsive nav menu i.e. mobile menu

Tags: css

I was trying to have a mobile menu for my website. when I apply **padding-left: 40px;** to **ul ul a** tag of the menu. It causes to overflow on right side. Can someone give me an advice to solve this issue please.

I know I should handle these codes but I don't know what is problematic

```
.mobile-menu ul a {
    padding-left : 40px;
}
.mobile-menu ul ul a {
    padding-left : 60px;
}
```

I could achieve following so far, and at this point I stuck

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atahta/3rof3qbr/)

[Screenshot](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-4n5_66sX57o/Ws-m-WlnN_I/AAAAAAAAAAk/y179tq9MGIs2Lgt7f1RK_EGRTx4QoNOEwCLcBGAs/s1600/2018-04-12_21-23-09.jpg)

And this is what I try to have:
[Screenshot](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-f-npQHBStms/Ws-xklus2PI/AAAAAAAAAA4/C3G_GjfcFykL3TeOO8qaWTxR9S3Jp5-vQCLcBGAs/s1600/2018-04-12_22-20-11.jpg)

Comment: `.mobile-menu a {width: auto;}`

Comment: @Blacksilver  No It didn't work, each child element seems longer that each parent on right side, it seems as if it overflows

Comment: Hmph, worked for me on the jsfiddle. Maybe I'm crazy.

Comment: Really? I added a screenshot of how it seems on my side

Comment: No idea. *shrug*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant to have same widths for "My Account" and "Cart", you can remove the `ul` around the Cart. That is a new list inside a list item and that is causing to change the width.

[Updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3rof3qbr/18/)

---

If you ment to have all the menu items in same width...

> Why the child element is longer than the first one?

Because of the browser default `-webkit-padding-start` CSS property. FYA, it is set to `40px`.

[image]

> How could I achieve that they will have same width?

Set `padding: 0` on the `ul`.

```
.mobile-menu ul {
  padding: 0;
}
```

[Another Version jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3rof3qbr/14/)

Comment: Why they don't have same widths on right side, child elements overflows outside the container? I don't want it to be.

Comment: I've supplied a screenshot of my mobile menu, you can see there on right side child elements overflow. I would like to know why that happens?

Comment: @user9637601 see [this updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3rof3qbr/26/), you need to adjust the styles to get what you want

Comment: overflow has gone on right side but this time child elements slide to left side. I wanted it to be like this:
[Screenshot](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-f-npQHBStms/Ws-xklus2PI/AAAAAAAAAA4/C3G_GjfcFykL3TeOO8qaWTxR9S3Jp5-vQCLcBGAs/s1600/2018-04-12_22-20-11.jpg)

Comment: @user9637601 [here is one way to do it](https://jsfiddle.net/3rof3qbr/37/), you will need to work on its scalability

Comment: Thanks your last tip was fine, it worked.

Comment: @user9637601 Glad it worked. Make sure it works for different list items as well, try adding some and tweak the styles if needed. Hit accept on this answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Set the width of the containing element, in this case the top level ul.
What you are doing currently is setting a width on ALL the anchors, no matter what level they are in.